# Insert,delete,update lock mysqld service

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySql database.

The beginning of the problem occurs on a server with very high specifications 80 Core and 200 GB RAM ( Ubuntu with Please Server Management System).

The details of the problem are as follows:

- We have a table with about 100,000 records,
- In the normal situation, and when I have no pressure on the server, all operations are very normal.
- But at times there are 4000 users on the server and we do any of the operations of insert, update, delete in particular, the Insert statement can take 2 cores from the CPU. And in these times when the server is on the move and there are users working online (we are talking about consuming 13% of the server’s capabilities.
- But at this time, if you make an insert process, it reaches up to 700%, and sometimes after two insertions, for example,
  Hanging of the Mysqld Service happens, looks like Dead Lock, and is only resolved by restarting mysqld several times.
- The table contains only 2 Indexes,
- And the information stored in it is just plain info, like name, description, link and stuff like that.
- Note that there is another table with approximately 3 million records, so this problem never becomes.

Of course, the problem is not from the code, because when I performed the process manually from within the data base, the problem appeared clearly.

I do not know what are the reasons that could be the cause of the occurrence of such a problem.

This is the my.cnf database configs:

```
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

#innodb_log_file_size = 250M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 10M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

max_connections = 1000

wait_timeout = 30
#query_cache_size=64M

#query_cache_limit=64M

#tmp_table_size=400M
key_buffer_size = 2G

slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/slowquery.log
long_query_time=5

log_queries_not_using_indexes = ON
```

Comment: you may get better results asking on dba.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com.  are you running just the mysql service on this server?  if not, consider doing so.  please edit your question to show output of `select version();` and `show create table yourtablename;`

Comment: bro, just use mongodb xd, it looks like you are having a lot of querys

Comment: See [advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions/3362#3362) on what to include in performance questions. key_buffer_size of 2G make it look like you have myisam tables. If you have innodb tables then you should have an innodb_buffer_pool_size setting= 30G (guess beyond default). Slow query log needs to be looked at. `log_queries_not_using_indexes` can cause excessive noise. Disable for now. Include common queries along with `explain {query}`. It mainly looks like an indexing problem.